# How do I reset my heroku database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I tried doing `heroku pg:info` and `heroku config` to get my `DATABASE_URL` as

```
DATABASE_URL:             postgres://yyxuzvlrgcccgx:aqM4txdIMrBVupbnaS-Z8XFUWE@ec2-54-204-15-248.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dasqm125it10r1
```

but then when I try something like

```
heroku pg:reset postgres://yyxuzvlrgcccgx:aqM4txdIMrBVupbnaS-Z8XFUWE@ec2-54-204-15-248.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dasqm125it10r1
```

I get

```
!    Unknown database: dasqm125it10r1. Valid options are: DATABASE_URL.
```

Why's that?

Comment: This should help http://someguyonrails.tumblr.com/post/34541604299/resetting-your-production-database-on-heroku

Comment: Can you try to rephrase your question, what are you trying to do? If you have the remote set up in your local git repo you do not need to specify the database url when running `heroku pg:reset`

Comment: i have a db with some test data inside that i want to get rid of. @maxcal :) i tried running `heroku pg:reset` alone but it's asking for `DATABASE_URL`

Answer (score 1):

You need to base the database URL to the heroku command or heroku doesnt know which database you are referring to.

Doing `heroku pg:info` if give you information about the database URL, which will look something like `=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAROON_URL (DATABASE_URL)`

Check out the heroku docs:https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql

Comment: lol. that command doesn't give me that output in the list of results.

Comment: Yes it does, there are three equal signs (===) and then your database URL.  If it doesn't please post what it is giving you.

Comment: I think DATABASE_URL is actually the argument. i thought it was a placeholder. got it fixed now. thanks.